# Need explanation on small length frames in wireshark

Tags: asp.net, networking, wireshark, f5

I see the following trace in wireshark when downloading an image form my .Net application.

What puzzles me is the sequence of 1514 bytes frame, followed by 61 bytes frame.

The image is streamed by an handler (ashx) of a .Net application which sits behind an F5.
Chunking option on the F5 is set to `RECHUNK`.

Assuming there is enough information (my networking level being very low), here are my questions :

- Is this expected network behavior?
- If not, does it hinder network performance?

[image: wireshark trace]

Comment: If that's being done by the F5, somebody familiar with F5 behavior might know what it is, but the rest of us might be able to do more if you can show the detailed dissection of one of the 61-byte frames.  It shouldn't be an ACK-only packet (not that there would be anything to ACK; from the lengths of the blurred-out IP addresses, all packets are from the same source and to the same destination), but it might contain either IP or TCP options.  I wouldn't expect that behavior, and it probably *does* hinder performance.

Comment: @GuyHarris Retrieving a js file without gzip or https encoding allowed me to view that the small frames contains a non redundant fragment of the javascript file. The small fragment has PUSH flag enabled.
I will try to disable rechunking, and see what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The small length frames went away by selecting Response `Chunking : Selective` in the Http profile on the F5

https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/ltm-http-profile-option-response-chunking

I still don't know what was the root cause of the problem